# MySQL - tranpose one row to columns dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Hello supposed to have a temporary table that having resultset like this:

[image]

And the **month column is changing dynamically** based on user input. Now I want my month column values (months) to become columns and under it was the amount and everything will be group by account_id.

I've searched every answers for this but I still can't get it. Here's my code but it is not returning accurately and I'm still lost here:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test`()
BEGIN
SET group_concat_max_len=2048;
SELECT CONCAT('
         SELECT account_id, month ',
       GROUP_CONCAT('
                  GROUP_CONCAT(IF(amount=',QUOTE(amount),',value,NULL))
                    AS `',REPLACE(amount,'`','``'),'`'
       ), '
         FROM     tmp_results
         GROUP BY account_id
       ')
INTO @sql
FROM (
  SELECT  account_id, month FROM tmp_results
) t;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Can someone help me step by step that I could understand it? PHP laravel step by step also are welcome. I'm a newbie developer. Thank you!

Comment: There are complicated and tricky ways to solve it partially on the database side, however i suggest you to get raw table from the database (your first screenshot) and then process it on PHP using few `foreach` and associative arrays. That's simpler to write/understand. Actually you want to make a "pivot" column, that's pretty common task. GIve it a try, share your progress, i'll help you with moving forward.

Comment: I don't know where to start in PHP, tried searching but I ended up with php native answers. I am using laravel and doing this for an api.